# WordPress AJAX query success but no data recieved

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm building a post filter on WordPress that filters posts from a custom post type based on the taxonomy they belong to. I'm using HTML select fields to get the taxonomy terms. I built an AJAX function to get this thing working.
The problem with my code is that it seems to be working. The AJAX request is success, but it doesn't return any data with the current setup I have (a function with parameters that uses the taxonomy variables on select field change to make a AJAX query). What I did test out was when I enter the variable values to the data object manually and just call the function without the parameters it outputs the data.
What am I'm missing over here, why doesn't my solution work as I want it to work.

My PHP function:

```
<?php

function my_archive_filter() {

    if (!isset($_GET['afp_nonce']) || !wp_verify_nonce($_GET['afp_nonce'], 'afp_nonce')) {
        die('Permission denied');
    }

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'project',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'orderby' => 'name',
        'order' => 'ASC'
    );

    $args['tax_query'] = array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
    );

    // Type Taxonomy
    if (isset($_GET['typefilter'])) {
        $args['tax_query'][] = array(
            'taxonomy' => 'type',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'operator' => "IN",
            'terms' => $_GET['typefilter']
        );
    }

    // Service Taxonomy
    if (isset($_GET['servicefilter'])) {
        $args['tax_query'][] = array(
            'taxonomy' => 'service',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'operator' => "IN",
            'terms' => $_GET['servicefilter']
        );
    }

    // Location Taxonomy
    if (isset($_GET['locationfilter'])) {
        $args['tax_query'][] = array(
            'taxonomy' => 'location',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'operator' => "IN",
            'terms' => $_GET['locationfilter']
        );
    }

    // Year Taxonomy
    if (isset($_GET['yearfilter'])) {
        $args['tax_query'][] = array(
            'taxonomy' => 'project-year',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'operator' => "IN",
            'terms' => $_GET['yearfilter']
        );
    }

    ob_start();
    $filter_posts = new WP_Query($args);
    if ($filter_posts->have_posts()): while ($filter_posts->have_posts()): $filter_posts->the_post();

            echo get_the_title();

        endwhile;
    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();
    $result = ob_get_clean();
    wp_send_json_success($result);
    wp_die();
}

add_action('wp_ajax_archive_filter', 'my_archive_filter');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_archive_filter', 'my_archive_filter');
?>
```

And my JS:

```
<script>
    (function ($) {

        function getProjects(projectType, projectService, projectLocation, projectYear) {
            var data = {
                action: 'archive_filter',
                afp_nonce: SiteParameters.afp_nonce,
                typefilter: projectType,
                servicefilter: projectService,
                locationfilter: projectLocation,
                yearfilter: projectYear
            };

            console.log(data);

            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                url: SiteParameters.admin_ajax,
                data: data,
                success: function (data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                    // $('.project-archive').html(data);
                    console.log(data);
                },

                error: function (errorThrown, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                    console.log(errorThrown);
                }
            });
        }

        $(document).on("change", '.project-filter__container select', function (e) {

            var projectType = $('.project-filter__type').val(),
                    projectService = $('.project-filter__service').val(),
                    projectLocation = $('.project-filter__location').val(),
                    projectYear = $('.project-filter__year').val();

            new getProjects(projectType, projectService, projectLocation, projectYear);
        });

    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: Check your browser devtools, do you see the AJAX request actually happening (check the network tab)?  Are the correct parameters sent (click the request and view headers in devtools/network tab)? What was the response (click response in devtools/network)?  Any errors on the console?

Comment: Yes, the request is actually happening, the success is true, but the data is empty: {success: true, data: ""}. I even have a console.log that tests if the variables are correct on the data object and they are.

Comment: So your PHP is not returning anything. Are you sure `my_archive_filter()` is actually being called?  Copy-paste the URL, with all params, into a browser, and start testing your PHP code to work out why you are not getting any responses.

Comment: Thanks. I think I got it where the problem lies. JS also picks the first value of the select even if its not selected. Will post the answer soon.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace your PHP code to:

```
    function my_archive_filter() {

        if (!isset($_GET['afp_nonce']) || !wp_verify_nonce($_GET['afp_nonce'], 'afp_nonce')) {
            die('Permission denied');
        }

        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'project',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'orderby' => 'name',
            'order' => 'ASC'
        );

        $args['tax_query'] = array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
        );

        // Type Taxonomy
        if (isset($_GET['typefilter'])) {
            $args['tax_query'][] = array(
                'taxonomy' => 'type',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'operator' => "IN",
                'terms' => $_GET['typefilter']
            );
        }

        // Service Taxonomy
        if (isset($_GET['servicefilter'])) {
            $args['tax_query'][] = array(
                'taxonomy' => 'service',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'operator' => "IN",
                'terms' => $_GET['servicefilter']
            );
        }

        // Location Taxonomy
        if (isset($_GET['locationfilter'])) {
            $args['tax_query'][] = array(
                'taxonomy' => 'location',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'operator' => "IN",
                'terms' => $_GET['locationfilter']
            );
        }

        // Year Taxonomy
        if (isset($_GET['yearfilter'])) {
            $args['tax_query'][] = array(
                'taxonomy' => 'project-year',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'operator' => "IN",
                'terms' => $_GET['yearfilter']
            );
        }
        $result = '';
        $filter_posts = new WP_Query($args);
        if ($filter_posts->have_posts()):
            while ($filter_posts->have_posts()): $filter_posts->the_post();

                $result .= get_the_title();

            endwhile;
        else:
            $result = 'No posts found';
        endif;


        echo $result;
        wp_die();
    }

    add_action('wp_ajax_archive_filter', 'my_archive_filter');
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_archive_filter', 'my_archive_filter');
```

Comment: Why is this better than the version I have written?

Comment: Please explain what you did, why that will fix the problem, and what was wrong.

Comment: I think it is something with using buffer and wp_send_json_success() function :)